# Unable to generate screenshot in Cucumber Extent Report

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, extentreports

I am unable to see screenshot getting captured in the Extent report for cucumber.

I have debuged and observed that the code gets executed, but the screenshot is not saved in the file of extent report or cucumber html report.

**Screenshot Code**

```
public void screenshot(Scenario scenario) {
```

if(scenario.isFailed()) { 
byte[] screenshot=SeleniumUtils.captureScreenshot(); scenario.public void screenshot(Scenario scenario) { embed(screenshot, "image1/png"); }

**Runner Class**

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
features = "src/test/java/features", tags = "@login_internal_user", glue 
 = {
    "stepDefinitions"
}, plugin = {
    "pretty",
    "rerun:src/test/java/features/rerun.txt",

 "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:",
    "html:reports"
}
)
```

public class loginRunner {

```
@AfterClass
public static void teardown() {
    SeleniumUtils.quitDriver();
}
}
```

Extent.properties file

```
# indicate which reporters to use

 extent.reporter.logger.start=true
 # point to any configuration used
 extent.reporter.logger.config=src/main/resources/extent-config.xml

  # specify output path
  extent.reporter.logger.out=reports/importsTeam-reports
  screenshot.dir=reports/importsTeam-reports/screenshots/
```

**Maven Properties**
Extent Cucumber Adapter version- 1.0.7
Cucumber Jars- 4.2.0

Answer (score 0):

You should use the html reporter. your property file should include,

```
extent.reporter.html.start = true
extent.reporter.html.config = <html config xml>
extent.reporter.html.out = <output path>
```

Comment: I tried that and still I do not see the screenshot. I also tried by using native cucumber html reporter, but don't see there also.

Comment: Are you getting html extent report?

Comment: Yes, But I observed that the the adapter is unable to pick configuration from extent.properties file.I tried below approach to debug:
1. Comment the values in extent.properties and check if report is generated. Report was generated successfully based on extent-report configuration xml.
2. I added the extent.properties as system.setproperty in a static block. Again, I was observed that report was getting generated without picking the configuration.

Comment: do you have the property file in the test resource folder. ? the screenshot are   getting captured under test-output folder by default.

Comment: yes, property file is present under the test resources folder but screenshots are not getting captured.

Comment: @VishalGada, Was this issue solved?

Comment: @jagruuti- this was solved